# FullCalendar Rails Engine Gem Add / View

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, fullcalendar

I created a new rails project and fullcalendar_engine is a gem and installed to the folder /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/fullcalendar_engine-1.0.6. If I add a new column to the fullcalendar_engine_series table in MySQL.  How can I add data from a new rails project to fullcalendar_engine_series table? And how can i view data the calendar by a specific user?  I understand that I can't modify the gem inside.

Answer (score 0):

Fork the gem, modifying the tables is almost as bad as modifying the code without forking it. What if a future version of the gem drops the table in a migration. It sounds like you want to add functionality to the gem without modifying the gem.

1. Fork gem
2. Add to Event and EventSeries

   belongs_to :user
3. Add user_id foreign keys to event tables via migration
4. Add to User

   has_many :events
   has_many :event_series
5. Bump the gem version
6. Include fork in Gemfile

Just a rough idea of how it could be done

Comment: That is helpful after I googled up about how to fork the gem.  I am still confused as to how I can add user_id has_many event/eventsiers in the model (User).